What kind of signal creates a triangle in the frequency domain?

What kind of signal creates a perfect triangle like this where the power is max when w = 0 rad/s and the signal slowly decreases in power as absoluteangular frequency goes up?
I suspect it might just be an ordinary sinusoid that I'm not looking at right, but I could be proven wrong.

$(\sin(x)/x)^2$. The Fourier transform of a sinc squared is a triangle.

To see why @Hilmar says that, find the property of the Fourier transform for two signals multiplied together, and find the spectrum of the sinc ($\sin(x) / x$) function.

I love the way that $\omega$ axis dips a little before changing course and starting to rise upwards,
